# How to call one method from another method from the same controller in Kohana 3

Tags: methods, controller, kohana

I have two methods and I want in first method to call the other method. They are in the same controller. I tried in this way but I'm getting error:

> Call to undefined method `Controller_User::getUser()`

My controller looks like that:

```php
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_User extends Controller {

   public function action_index (){
       $id = $this->request->param('id');
       $user = self::getUser($id);
  }

 public function action_getUser ($id){
      //some code here
  }


}
```

Comment: The method is named `action_getUser`, not just `getUser`. Also `$this->action_getUser($id)` would be working (if you don't want that, declare the method as [`static`](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php))

Comment: Thanks, it's fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions are in same class so use $this-> to call other method in same class in your case as kingkero mentioned in comment user $this->action_getUser($id)